# Dynamic content in GlobalParameters in Azure Data Factory V2 ML Batch execution web service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, ml-studio

I'm trying to use Dynamic Content within the GlobalParameters on a ML Batch Execution module in Azure Data Factory V2.

Seems everything I try comes up with the same errors.  Please see attached screen shots.

[image: Trying to do dynamic content globalParameters]

Here is the only bit of documentation I can find on the subject ...

[image: documentation]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is just a bug.  Whenever you click on Add Dynamic Content and click Finish it wipes out all your parameters setup manually and gives you an error about GlobalParameters cannot be a String type.

The secret is to setup your parameters manually.  Then use the Dynamic Content window just to allow you to choose your dynamic parts.  It will always say your syntax is wrong but don't worry.  Just COPY your code and click CANCEL on the Dynamic Content window.  Then paste the dynamic code into the manually created parameters.

This will work!  Hoever, if you accidentally click Add Dynamic Content and Click Finish, it will wipe all your parameters and you'll have to start again.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, just using `@variables('input1')` as parameter:

[image]